# MySQL Syntax Error #1064 with ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

For the life of me, I cannot find out why MySQL doesn't like this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personnel
(
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    role VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    line_manager INTEGER NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (role) REFERENCES roles(name)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (line_manager) REFERENCES personnel(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The resulting output from MySQL after inserting this is `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE CASCADE
 UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (line_manager) REFERENCES personnel(id)
' at line 10`.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the error you pasted is unrelated to the ddl; you have a missing `ON` keyword before `UPDATE CASCADE` in a constraint definition just before another one that references the `staff` table

Comment: Ah, sorry, I partially lied. I changed the DDL from `staff` to `personnel` to avoid further confusion. The error has been updated.

Comment: fair enough; still, the error you get points to the fact that mysql was expecting the `ON` keyword but is didn't find it

Comment: Actually, this example now works. A similar example doesn't though - I'm going to see if the syntax error refers to tables that haven't been created yet, but I thought that would give a different error.

Comment: Nope; just read your error string. It starts with `DELETE`, it's a syntax error, so there was no `ON` keyword there.

Answer (score 2):

hey i have check your mysql query and it works I think you should check the following constraints

```
1) table roles must have same **engine** that is InnoDB
2) the length of both column that is personnel(role) and roles(name) must be **equal**
3) column roles(name) must be **primary key**
```

Just check this things and i think it will work

Comment: Yeah, this particular example works now. I've just got to figure out why the rest aren't working when the syntax is practically identical. I'll delete this question as it's no longer relevant